# Does a CREATE OR REPLACE statement in BigQuery create a downtime for the table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Say table `sample` exists. We then run a `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sample AS (...)`. Will that table be accessible throughout the process? For example while we perform the CREATE OR REPLACE statement and we also have another job querying the table. Is there a chance that we get a `404 Not found` exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you won't. The write is atomic and immediately available, no downtime. However, all the running queries that already read the data and continue to process them won't have the new data (because they live in memory and are no longer read from the BigQuery storage)